# DOM not loading prevents focus() in TextBoxFor control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom

I'm not sure why my focus() isn't working on one view.

I have a class in JQuery, passed through a master page, defined as:
    $(".focus").focus();

This works for text boxes define elsewhere in my code.  For example:

```
<td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.PhoneTypeId, phoneTypeListItems, new{@class="focus"}) %></td>
```

But on one view with similar code, the focus is not set:

```
<td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(de => de.EmailAddress1, new {@class="focus"})%></td>
```

If my focus class is working with other controls then it can't be my jquery.  I've tried many options to set this including $("#EmailAddress1").focus() and defining my own jquery in the same view and other options beside this.  The only thing that works without clicking in the textbox itself is to hit the reload button (Chrome and IE9), which leads me to believe that the DOM is not loading.  But in my jquery I use:
    $(document).ready(function () {

I don't know how to fix this problem.  Can anyone help?

P.S. In further tests, I've found that other class elements in JQuery work.  For instance, 
    <%=Html.TextBoxFor(de => de.EmailAddress1, new { @class = "focus phoneNumber" })%>
Both phoneNumber and focus are in the same .js 
    $(".focus").focus();
    $(".phoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");

But only phoneNumber will display and focus will not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide **ID** if you want to set focus class using jQuery like this:

```
<td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(de => de.EmailAddress1, new {@class="focus", id = "EmailAddress", name = "EmailAddress"})%></td>
```

Now In **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#EmailAddress").focus();
});
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not it.  As I mentioned previously, focus is set using the same pattern in other textboxes but not in my EmailAddress1 control.